# How to make username display in suite crm

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am new to suite crm and what I find missing is I cannot find the username displayed in the items view in Suite Crm.

**What do I mean is**

> Like we can have multiple users in the Suite Crm who have privilege in
>   Suite Crm. They can make the accounts entry or contacts or contracts
>   entry. How would a Administrator user know who is responsible for the
>   respective entry.

I don't know how to find or add this features in Suite Crm. Is it really missing in Suite Crm or there is something I am missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to edit the list view (from studio) of each module , drag the field of 'created by' . 
This will help administrator to view who create this contact or account .